# Javascript: cached function property vs new value

Tags: javascript, function

A basic function:

```
function myStuff(a,b,c){
    var _c = _c || c || {};
    console.log(_c);
}
```

The idea is to use a cached value if used before, or a new value if new/different.

The question is: if the function invoke does not include the third property why the `console.log(_c)` shows undefined or how can I write this line `var _c = _c || c || {};` better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured. Having this code `if ( c === undefined ) { c = {}; }` solves the issue with undefined `c`:

```
function myStuff(a,b,c){
  if ( c === undefined ) { c = {}; }
  var _c = _c || c || {};
  console.log(_c);
}
```

because

```
_c = c || _c || {};
```

does not count the last case for `{}`.

Answer (score 2):

the scope of the variable you defined is the function itself, therefore, it is redefined every time you call the function.

the correct way to cache a variable, is to define it in the parent scope of the function:

```
var _c;
function myStuff(a,b,c){
    _c = c || _c || {};
    console.log(_c);
}
```

read more about js scopes here: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: only in the first call. after that it gets cached

Comment: but the part of ` || {}` is ignored when function is used without third property.

Comment: mabe in the console you see undefined, becase calling the function return undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can store the cache inside the function itself

```
function myStuff(a,b,c){
    if (!myStuff.cache) {
        myStuff.cache = {};
    }

    var cache = myStuff.cache;
    c = cache.c = cache.c || c || {};

    console.log(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If yout want to access `_c` external value you have to use the function like this:

```
function myStuff(a,b,c){
    var _c = window._c || c || {};
    console.log(_c);
}
```